# Как написать на Питоне команду для выдачи рандомной фразы из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для бота ВК нужно сделать так что бы с текстового файла что бы рандомно брало названия фильмов, и и скидывало человеку написавшему команду.
Вот что нашел в интернете, но сам код почему-то не правильно работает.

```
             elif response == "аниме":
               a = open("anime.txt")
               a = a.readline()
               vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": (random.choice(a)), "random_id": 0})
```

Comment: `a.readline` **s** `()`.

Comment: `"random_id": 0` - очень рандомный.

Comment: что значит "не правильно"? open().readlines() получить итератор по всем строкам файла

Comment: Не правильно в том плане, что при отправке команды, бот отвечает непонятными символами. Пример:
Текст Сообщения: аниме

Текст Сообщения: С‡РёС‚С‹СЂРёСЃ

Comment: Кодировка, а не шифровка...

Comment: @БогданСтасюк ответил по поводу символов

Answer (score 0):

По поводу кодировки:

В строке `a = open("anime.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")` где открываешь файл, указываешь кодировку в твоем случае utf-8

Код:

```
         elif response == "аниме":
           a = open("anime.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
           a = a.readline()
           vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": (random.choice(a)), "random_id": 0})
```